# Defining path to file in separate directory in include statement

Tags: include

I have a main document that includes a list of 'include' statements. Could someone please help me with defining the path to the files that need to be included.

My directory structure is:

```
Book Title
        Matter
            Front Matter (containing 'main.tex')
        Chapters
            Chapter One (containing 'one.tex')
```

I would appreciate some guidance in this, please.

Many thanks,
Mike

Comment: It isn't clear what your question is. It's a bit easier really if you put main.tex one level up, then you can use `\include{chapter-one/one}` (don't put spaces in directory names:-) but if you put Book-Title//: into TEXINPUTS tex will find all the files anyway so you can just use `\include{one}` whatever your directory structure

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, what is the default for `$TEXINPUTS`? My `echo` on it returns nothing.

Comment: @Sigur The default environment variable is empty so setting texinputs of .//: makes it recursively search the current directory then (because of trailing :) search wherever it was going to search, the default effective value is set cross platform in texmf.cnf rather than via an environment variable]